# maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object on Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

```
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as hc

dendogram  = hc.dendrogram(hc.linkage(X_reduced, method = 'ward'))

plt.title('Dendrogram')
plt.xlabel('Customers')
plt.ylabel('Euclidean Distances')
plt.show()
```

Whenever i tried to run the code, it always crashed. im still new to Python so i havent understood yet how to use `sys.getrecursionlimit()` to set the recursion limit manually. my data consists of 29000+ data and 23 columns. so id be so thankful if it could be solved, thank u so much!^^